# How to use gl Scissor properly to implemented popup

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a popview on of current webglview.

My plan goes as follows: Whenever I need to a show popup,  I create a scissorRect and start rendering popup scene to it. I was hoping the content of previous screen will be preserved. As I understand setScissor must prevent clearing of content outside the popup. But with following code content outside the popup will be black. Note glclear automatically called when renderer.render() is called

```
        if (this.options.showPopUP) {
            this.renderer.setScissorTest(true);

            this.renderer.setViewport(popupViewPort.x, popupViewPort.y, popupViewPort.z, popupViewPort.w);
            this.renderer.setScissor(popupViewPort.x, popupViewPort.y, popupViewPort.z, popupViewPort.w);

            this.renderer.render(this.popUpScene, camera.camera);
        }





    if (!this.options.showPopUP) {
        var size = this.renderer.getSize();
        this.renderer.setScissorTest(false);

        this.renderer.setViewport(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        this.renderer.setScissor(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
        this.renderer.render(this.scene, camera.camera);

    }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

*"I was hoping the content of previous screen will be preserved"* and *"Note glclear automatically called when renderer.render() is called"* conflicts with eachother? You should render both and render the popup after the non-popup content.

```
var size = this.renderer.getSize();
this.renderer.setScissorTest(false);

this.renderer.setViewport(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
this.renderer.setScissor(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
this.renderer.render(this.scene, camera.camera);

if (this.options.showPopUP) {
    this.renderer.setScissorTest(true);

    this.renderer.setViewport(popupViewPort.x, popupViewPort.y, popupViewPort.z, popupViewPort.w);
    this.renderer.setScissor(popupViewPort.x, popupViewPort.y, popupViewPort.z, popupViewPort.w);

    this.renderer.render(this.popUpScene, camera.camera);
}
```

You might want to clear the color/z-buffer before rendering the popup.

Comment: glclear should obey the ScissorRect right? Its not supposed clear non-popup content?

Comment: @user3804449 thats true. Are you sure that the _"Note glclear automatically called when renderer.render() is called"_ is done without resetting the scissors/viewport. When a resize is done, the buffer is recreated and it will be blank. What about a multiple (swapchain) buffer count. So the content of the previous draw/buffer is not reliable. Every time a frame is needs to be rendered, it should be redrawn completely. If you don't want to redraw/calculate the whole background. You could render it to a texture.